Is it necessary to extend Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel for all custom model classes in Magento 2?
Is it necessary to extend Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel for all custom model classes in Magento 2?
I am working on a custom model that does not involve any database interactions (e.g., saving, loading, or deleting records), and I noticed that AbstractModel depends on deprecated components like \Magento\Framework\Registry. Is it mandatory to extend Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel for all custom model classes?

No, don't need to extend the class which we don't need it.

What you're describing sounds like a Data Transfer Object (DTO) or a Data Model, which is intended for almost exactly what you're looking for. A simple object representing keys/values of data, wrapped in an object without extra dependencies for persisting to a database.
I'd consider looking at and extending \Magento\Framework\DataObject as it will allow you to bootstrap a DTO quickly with any data you want with use of magic methods.
If you later needed that DTO's data to be persisted to a database, you could back it with a Model, Resource Model, Collection, etc as needed.
Data Object Example

Data object uses magic methods to allow dynamic get/set/uns/has of data this is good initially for prototyping/quick usage
Data object has other interesting features under the hood (in the base class) for data manipulation like toXml, toJson, etc.
No dependencies other than implementing \ArrayAccess for iterating the object data like like an array
If you happen to use PHPStorm and have the official Magento plugin, they add tool menu's for generating a Data Model / DTO, like the example below but with real getter/setter methods for the data
If you generate an Entity with the Magento plugin, you'll notice that there is a split of the Model VS Data Model. This move helps separate the Data Model from the Abstract Model you're describing that has a lot of code assuming persistence to a database.

<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Data;

class FooBar extends \Magento\Framework\DataObject
{
}

Usage
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class SomeProcess
{
    public function __construct(
        protected \Vendor\Module\Model\Data\FooBarFactory $fooBarFactory
    ) {}

    public function execute(): FooBar
    {
        // Do some unit of work

        // Maybe the unit of work wants to share fooBar across problem domain
        $fooBar = $this->fooBarFactory->create();
        $fooBar->setIsComplete(true);
        $fooBar->setErrors([]);
        $fooBar->setMessage('some message about unit of work or process');

        return $fooBar;
    }
}

<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class AnotherProcess
{
    public function __construct(
        protected \Vendor\Module\Model\SomeProcess $someProcess
    ) {}

    public function execute(): void
    {
        $fooBar = $this->someProcess->execute();

        $fooBarData = $fooBar->getData();
        // Output of getData
        /*
        [
            'is_complete' => true,
            'errors' => [],
            'message' => 'some message about unit of work or process'
        ]
        */
    }
}

Of course you can also just create plain PHP class with properties and achieve the same result.
